# How to count items in row and append div after

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to write a function that counts the number of items in the a row. Then, I want to insert a div after that many items so that it takes up a whole row below the items counted.

Here is my function so far. Not even sure if I'm on right track... Please reference this CodePen for more info: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/gmYBJy

```
var parentSelector = $('.container');
var childSelector = $('.box');

function countFirstRowItems(parentSelector, childSelector){
        var count = 0, theTop = undefined;
        $(parentSelector + " > " + childSelector).each(function(){
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
            if(theTop === undefined){
                theTop = thisTop;
            }
            if(thisTop != theTop){
                return false;
            }
            count++;
        });
        return count;
    }

console.log(countFirstRowItems());
```

Comment: You want to insert the div after the last item in the row?

Comment: What exactly is going to be your HTML structure, and what is that you are trying to count? Are these div's within a div, or is this a table with <tr>'s and <td>'s? The codepen example doesn't have legal HTML.

Comment: You want to add a `div` after an amount of `.box` elements? If the amount for example is 3 then you want this: `.box - .box - .box - DIV - .box - .box - .box - DIV - .box ...`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "items" and "row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function separateRows(parent, children) {
  var $elems = $(parent + ">" + children);                       // get the elements
  var top = $elems.first().offset().top;                         // get the offsetTop of the first
  var n = 1;                                                     // n will be the number of items in the same row
  while(n < $elems.length && $elems.eq(n).offset().top == top)   // while there still elements and the current element got the same offsetTop as the first, increment n
    n++;
  var $div = $("<div class='div'></div>");                       // the div that will take a whole row (see CSS)
  $div.insertAfter(parent + ">" + children + ":nth-child(" + n + "n)"); // add the div after each n elements
}

separateRows(".container", ".box");
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around; /* I added this too (not important though) */
  background-color: #333;
}

.box, .div {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%; /* to take a whole row */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the insertion of the `div`, but it does address what's wrong with the code right now.

These lines:

```
var parentSelector = $('.container');
var childSelector = $('.box');
```

go and get you a JQuery wrapped set of matching elements. They are not valid as selectors, so when you then try to do this:

```
$(parentSelector + " > " + childSelector).each(function(){
```

The code crashes because you are not using strings here, you are using objects.

Instead, just pass the values as strings directly to the function.

Also, you bump up `count` by `1` if you are trying to get the number of elements found.

Lastly, don't initialize variables at `undefined` as this is what they will initialize at if you don't initialize them at all. Instead, initialize them at 'null' and check for that.

```js
function countFirstRowItems(p, c){

  var count = 1, theTop = null;
 
  $(p + " > " + c).each(function(){
    var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
    console.log(this);
    
    if(!theTop){
      theTop = thisTop;
    }
    
    if(thisTop != theTop){
      return false;
    }
    
    count++;
 });
  
  return count;
}

console.log(countFirstRowItems(".container", ".box"));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #333;
}
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(p + " > " + c)`, `$(p).children(c)` might be clearer.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but I left it with the OP's syntax to illustrate what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to target the last child and apply the pseudo after class.

```
.box:last-child:after{ }
```

## Code Pen